# How do you set an environment variable within a c# AWS lambda function?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that sends out a message to AWS SNS when certain conditions appear in a SQL database.  This lambda function fires every 5 minutes to check for this condition.

It works fine, and sends the appropriate message.  However, once it has sent the message I don't want it to send it every 5 minutes until it is resolved.  I would rather it only send out the message every 5 hours after that.  Mainly because if I'm away on the weekend I don't want to be bombarded with an email or text every 5 minutes when I'm away from my computer.

One possible solution was to have an environment variable that stores the last time a message was sent, LastTimeMessageSent.  Getting the value of the environment variable is easy and works fine

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LastTimeMessageSent");
```

However, when I do this

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("LastTimeMessageSent", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
```

It doesn't work.  No exception or error message.  I can't seem to find anywhere in the documentation or the web that describes how to do this or explains why  this wouldn't work.

How do I set the environment variable?  If I'm not able to do that inside the lambda what is the correct way to accomplish what I need to accomplish?

Comment: Environment variables can not be set for Lamba Function from within the code. Also lambda functions does not persist anything inside them. Lambda functions are not active all the time. They are triggered only when their target event happens.

Comment: You might want to save the state of the message in database so that whenever lambda is triggered it would first check in the database and then decide whether to send an email or not. If you can explain the use case in detail a better solution can be suggested

Comment: Can I suggest you edit the title to say AWS lambda?

Comment: Saving it to the database could work.  That's a good option.  Seems like if I can read from environment variables for an AWS lambda I should be able to write to them as well.

Comment: Chetan, put your database suggestion as an answer, and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to set an environment variable at the OS level within the Lambda invocation because that Lambda container may not be reused, and you may have other containers running that wouldn't get the updated value. Changing AWS Lambda function environment variable values necessitates tearing down any containers Lambda currently has your function deployed in, and building new containers with the new environment variable value. This is why you need to use something outside the Lambda container, like DynamoDB, to store values that you want to change via your Lambda function.

Comment: I understand that.  But in my case it's just running once every 5 minutes.  No parallel running here.  Just something to monitor my database, and send me an alarm when a certain situation occurs.  If the environment variables can be loaded up every time it runs when I change it in the console, why can't it simply load it up when I change it from the lambda?  I understand why that wouldn't work in a parallel running environment.  But that's not my scenario.  Is there a better technology to use to accomplish this other than lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS Lambda functions run in a temporary container environment. They can also run in parallel across many host systems.

While a Lambda function can access environment variables, these are specifically set when the container is created for the Lambda function. Once the function has finished running, the environment might be **thrown away**. (If a function is invoked often enough, the environment *might* be kept for future executions.)

Thus, using environment variables is not a way to persist data.

Some other options are:

- Store information in the [AWS Systems Manager **Parameter Store**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html)
- Store information in an **Amazon DynamoDB** table